# How to get array from JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to get a list of users from JSON object here is my JSON response :

```
{"users":[{"user":"David David","id_user":"10"},{"user":"Ale Camp","id_user":"14"}],"success":true}`
```

And here is my code :

```
try {
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(responseContent);
    JSONArray users = jobj.getJSONArray("users");
    String utilisateur = String.valueOf(users.get(Integer.parseInt("user")));
    Log.e("users",String.valueOf(utilisateur));
}
 catch (JSONException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the app crashes with this error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "utilisateur"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
    try {
     JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(responseContent);
    JSONArray users = jobj.getJSONArray("users");

    for(i=0;i<users.length();i++){
    JSONObject jobj1 = users.getJSONObject(i);
    String user=jobj1.getString("user");
    String user_id=jobj1.getString("id_user");
    }
}
 catch (JSONException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

let me know if this work or not

Answer (score 1):

It is because the value associated to the key `user` is of type `String` and not `Integer`. Probably you meant to use the key `id_user`. If you instead meant to take really the `user` than just remove the parsing part:

```
String utilisateur = users.get("user");
```

Comment: because I got error saying get(int) in JSONArray can not be applied to (java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

This is problem `Integer.parseInt("user")` you can't convert "user" to integer. 
If you want to print names of user then you should do:

Change this:

```
String utilisateur = String.valueOf(users.get(Integer.parseInt("user")));
    Log.e("users",String.valueOf(utilisateur));
```

With:

```
for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++)
{
JsonObject job=users.getJSONObject(i);
     String utilisateur = job.getString("user");
        Log.e("users",utilisateur);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your value is already in type of string so you not needed to parse value

so try with

```
try {
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(responseContent);
    JSONArray users = jobj.getJSONArray("users");
    String utilisateur = String.valueOf(users.getString("user"));
    Log.e("users",utilisateur);
}
 catch (JSONException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through these

```
try {
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(responseContent);
JSONArray users = jobj.getJSONArray("users");

for(int i =0;i<users.length();i++)
  {
  JSONObject user_details = users.get(i);
  String username =  user_details.getString("user");
  Log.e("users",""+username);
  }
}
catch (JSONException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 try {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(responseContent);
        JSONArray users = jobj.getJSONArray("users");
        for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = users.getJSONObject(i);
            String userName = obj.getString("user");
            String userId = obj.getString("id_user");

            Log.e("userName: ",userName);
            Log.e("userId: ",String.valueOf(userId));
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```